# Wordpress site in subdirectory load site in main directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two wordpress site one in main directory (public_html) and another one is in subdirectory staging. I already configure all the settings in subdirectory site with http://example.com/staging but when I load http://example.com/staging it redirect to Page Not Found in main site and not in staging site. I set the .htaccess file in staging subdirectory like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this in on the main site in main directory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Anybody can help me with this issue and my staging site can load properly ? Thank you before.

Comment: `RewriteBase /staging/`  to `RewriteBase /staging`

Comment: @Noman I just try it but still not working. Thx.

Comment: can you rename your `staging` to `stage-site` in htaccess also change the directory name

Comment: @Noman Still not working with rename. What is the reason why I must rename it ?

Comment: this might be some url pattern issue, however i m using 2 wp in public_html one in main directory and second in subdirectory having name of `lading-page`